# Hibernate configuration mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hi I am trying to configure hibernate with mysql.

I'm using Maven with IntelliJ to get my dependencies.

My hibernate config file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">SYS</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory</property>
        <mapping resource="Person.hdm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have a mapping class Person.hdm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Person">

        <id name="FirstName"/>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm getting the following stack ..

```
222  [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration  - HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:24)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.translate(Log4jLogger.java:64)
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.isEnabled(Log4jLogger.java:39)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.logv(Logger.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger.tracev(CoreMessageLogger_$logger.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3DTDEntityResolver.resolveEntity(EJB3DTDEntityResolver.java:58)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:646)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:729)
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:22)
    ... 3 more
```

Any help would be most appreciated,

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Googling your exception brings up quite a few results, including this one - https://community.jboss.org/thread/63422. You might want to verify that you are using the correct versions of all your libraries.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: "Thrown if an application tries to access or modify a specified field of an object, and that object no longer has that field."

Log4jLogger looks to be the culprit, I notice that it is 'org.jboss.logging' .. is hibernate expecting a different version? Looks like an environment specific logger (ie Jboss, the app server), are you running this in JBoss?